# Most efficient way to search records for oldest entry based on criteria

Tags: mysql

Very junior learner here looking to perform a query in a more efficient manner now that the database I am working with is getting substantially larger (and will continue to expand).

Basically I have two tables (partners and notes) where I store customer contact information and the notes that correspond to calls made. When the database was much smaller, the query below worked just fine for the purpose I needed. However, now that the database has substantially expanded, the query time is taking far too long, and timing out in many cases. I was wondering if there was perhaps a more efficient way to perform this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT
partners.objectid,
partners.partner,
notes.note,
notes.datecreated,
notes.timecreated
FROM
notes
JOIN
partners
ON
notes.partnerid=partners.objectid
WHERE
partners.province
=
'BC'
AND
partners.type
=
'2'
ORDER BY
notes.datecreated DESC, notes.timecreated DESC) as noteq
GROUP BY
partner
ORDER BY
datecreated ASC, timecreated ASC
LIMIT 1
```

I basically have a button which when clicked will search for the oldest existing note in the database and then returns the customer associated with that note. If there's any additional information I could provide, please let me know. Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I think the key is to avoid subquery.

Try this kind of approach :

```
SELECT
    partners.objectid,
    partners.partner,
    notes.note,
    notes.datecreated,
    notes.timecreated

FROM notes

JOIN partners
    ON notes.partnerid=partners.objectid

WHERE partners.province = 'AB'
    AND partners.type = '2'

GROUP BY partners.partner

ORDER BY
    notes.datecreated ASC,
    notes.timecreated ASC

LIMIT 1
```

All can probably be done in one query, because in query you posted you avoid subquery's ORDER BY with the top query's ORDER BY and the GROUP BY can be done directly in the subquery.

Comment: This does work but seems to take the same amount of time on my localmachine here (just using WAMP)... Perhaps part of the problem is the limited system resources being allocated to the database locally?

Comment: The query optimizer probably does its work. Did you define indexes ?

Comment: Heh no I have not. This is something I most certainly need to do.

Comment: Ahhh jeez that made such a big difference. And this query is most certainly better.

Answer (score 1):

The query that @aurel.g wrote may perform quickly, but I don't think it does what you want.  You seem to want the oldest note and to get the partner with that.

The query above (and possibly your query too) groups by partner, choosing an arbitrary note.  It will then return the oldest of the arbitrary notes.  This is not the same thing.

So, if you want the oldest note with the associated information, you need something like:

```
SELECT partners.objectid, partners.partner, notes.note, notes.datecreated, notes.timecreated
FROM notes join
     partners
     ON notes.partnerid=partners.objectid
WHERE partners.province = 'AB' and
      partners.type = '2'
ORDER BY notes.datecreated ASC, notes.timecreated ASC
LIMIT 1
```

The critical difference is that this query has no `group by` statement.